# Upload multiple images with JavaScript in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, asp.net, file-upload, sharepoint-2010

For uploading multiple images, I am using this javascriptL

```
    function AddMoreImages() {
        if (!document.getElementById && !document.createElement)
            return false;
        var fileUploadarea = document.getElementById("fileUploadarea");
        if (!fileUploadarea)
            return false;
        var newLine = document.createElement("br");
        fileUploadarea.appendChild(newLine);
        var newFile = document.createElement("input");
        newFile.type = "file";
        newFile.setAttribute("class", "fileUpload");

        if (!AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId)
            AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId = 100;
        newFile.setAttribute("id", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
        newFile.setAttribute("name", "FileUpload" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
        var div = document.createElement("div");
        div.appendChild(newFile);
        div.setAttribute("id", "div" + AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId);
        fileUploadarea.appendChild(div);
        AddMoreImages.lastAssignedId++;
    }
<div id="fileUploadarea">
                                    <asp:FileUpload ID="UploadImage" runat="server" CssClass="fileUpload" />
</div>
```

But the problem is, when I am uploading multiple images with 2MB size, the JavaScript is not working and the page doesn't postback to my page.

Answer (score 1):

> But problem is when am upload multiple images with 2mb size...

It's likely your running into the default maximum upload size that's set for ASP.NET (4MB).  you can add this to your web.config to increase from the default:

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime executionTimeout="240" maxRequestLength="20480" />
</system.web>
```

This would increase the maximum upload size to 20MB at a time.

There's a pretty detailed article about this topic here if you'd like to read further: [Large file uploads in ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/01/08/large-file-uploads-in-asp-net.aspx).

*Note: You said the "javascript was not working", but didn't really elaborate.  If you could expand on that, I'd be glad to take another look*